# Create an expression that uses Any

Tags: c#, linq-expressions

I have a constant String, "ello orld"

I have a class with a text property set to "Hello World";

```
public class Hi
{
   public String Text {get; set;} = "Hello World";
}

Hi hiObj = new Hi();
```

I want to build a Permute Algorithm defined as such:

```
"ello World".Split(" ").All(y => hiObj.Text.Split(" ").Any(x => x.Contains(y)));
```

I have a function defined as such.

```
public override Expression GetExpression(MemberExpression member, ConstantExpression constant1)
{
...
}
```

In the above function, member refers to hiObj.Text while constant1 refers to "ello World".

How do I form this expression?

So far my attempt.

```
public class PermuteAlgorithm: OperationBase
{
     private readonly MethodInfo stringSplit = typeof(string).GetMethod("Split", new[]{ typeof(string), typeof(StringSplitOptions)});

     private readonly MethodInfo stringContainsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[]{ typeof(string)});

     private readonly MethodInfo enumerableAny= typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).First(x => x.Name == "Any" && x.GetParameters().Count() == 2);

public override Expression GetExpression(MemberExpression member, ConstantExpression constant1)
{
     Expression parameterY = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "y");
     Expression memberContains = Expression.Call(member, stringContainsMethod, parameterY);
     var anyLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<String, bool>>(memberContains, (ParameterExpression)parameterY);

     Expression memberSplitExpression = Expression.Call(member, stringSplit, Expression.Constant(" "), Expression.Constant(StringSplitOptions.emoveEmptyEntries));

      //Error below statement
      Expression memberSplitAndAnyExpression = Expression.Call(memberSplitExpression, enumberableAny, anyLambda);
}

}
```

Comment: Side note: if you define a variable as an expression (ie `Expression<Func<bool>> m = () => "ello World".Split(...)...`), you can then use the "expression debug view" in the debugger (while mouse over `m` in this case) to see how that expression is built. (there's also some nice VS extensions to augment this). You can also stick it in sharplab or manually decompile it and you'll see how it's built as well (though a bit more difficult to visualize)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Enumerable.Any` is an extension method. The compiler lets you write `thing.Any(...)`, but it actually turns this into a call to `Enumerable.Any(x, ...)` at compile-time.

You're trying to call the instance method `Any` on `memberSplitExpression`, but you should instead be trying to call the static method `Enumerable.Any`, passing `memberSplitExpression` as the first parameter.

Something like:

```
Expression.Call(enumberableAny, memberSplitExpression, anyLambda)
```

Comment: It says System.ArgumentExeption: 'Method Boolean Any xxx is a generic method definition(Parameter 'method')

Comment: Right, `enumerableAny` refers to the method `Enumerable.Any<T>`, and you need it to refer to `Enumerable.Any<string>`. Use `enumerableAny.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string))`